# grpcurl: how to invoke bi-directional streaming rpc in powershell?

Tags: powershell, grpcurl

How to invoke, in Powershell, bi-directional streaming rpc or server streaming rpc with grpcurl.exe and be able to send/receive messages continuously?

I have:

```
service Info {
  ...
  rpc LocationUpdates ( stream .reqLocation ) return ( stream .resNewLocation ) {}
  ...
}
```

I use:

```
grpcurl -vv -H $token -import-path $proto_path -proto info.proto -d $request_message $server Info/LocationUpdates
```

and I get:

```
Resolved method descriptor:
rpc LocationUpdates ( stream .reqLocation ) returns ( stream .resNewLocation );

Request metadata to send:
authorization: Bearer ...

Response headers received:
(empty)

Response trailers received:
content-type: application/grpc
Sent 1 request and received 0 responses
```

In BloomRPC it works, but I prefer grpcurl from command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please try this:

```
grpcurl -vv -H $token -import-path $proto_path -proto info.proto -d @ $server Info/LocationUpdates<<EOF
$data1
$data2
$data3
EOF
```

you will receive three responses from server.